# piping text file contents with unsaved modifications to a command with the neovim interactive terminal emulator

Tags: vim, nvim

I want to know if theres an equivalent to `:w !cmd` for the nvim terminal emulator. Like `:te cat % | cmd` is almost there but you would have to save the file before using it.

Is there another way?

Like can you use other registers as substitutions in commands like you can with %?

Comment: Do you mean `!`, as in `!!cmd` to pipe the current line through a program (with the output replacing the current line)? or `!}cmd` to do the same for a paragraph (I use this all the time to pipe a paragraph through `par` for reformatting)?  and similar for some other directional keys (e.g. `!G` for current line to EOF), and for visual blocks selected with `V`. If that's not what you mean, then you'll have to explain your question in more detail.

Comment: That is not what I'm asking for. I sometimes like to run scripts or script segments before I save the changes (eg `:w !bash`). This command does not add or replace text in the file like filter commands do, it just runs the command and sends the modified text through the stdin of the command. My issue is that in neovim, for technical reasons, the shell that these commands run in is not interactive like it would be in vim. `:terminal` is neovim's interactive alternative but I'm struggling testing interactive scripts with it the same way I do with other scripts.

Comment: I can't say i've ever really needed to do that (I just suspend vim when i need to test whatever script i'm writing) but the only real difference between what you're asking for and using `!` is that it replaces the input line/paragraph/whatever with the output of whatever program you run (incl. par, fmt, sed, awk, even bash)....and that's easily undone just be pressing `u`. It's not at all hard to write a macro to use `!` and then `u`.

Comment: BTW, there's a SE for vi/vim/neovim etc at https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh, I should have looked harder, I just searched 'nvim stackexchange', clicked on the first search result I found and posted on the same subdomain. And its not really about 'needing' to do it the way I'm doing it, I just like doing it like that. (also the filter commands and the 'write to pipe' commands  use the same non interactive shell on neovim, it has the same problem for the situation I described.) I might ask around elsewhere. But Thanks for the input.